# Custom roles on an Authorize attribute in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, action-filter

Here is my code:

```
[HttpGet, Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult ActivityLog()
{
  'code to do stuff

  return View(model);
}
```

It's pretty simple - if you are in the "Admin" role you can get into this action.  However I have a custom ActionFilter that populates my IPrinciple with all the custom claims (I cant use ADFS to send the claims because I have ONE ADFS for multiple sites so my claims have to be for that specific site).

```
public class CustomFilter: ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
      'go get custom claims
    }
  }
}
```

I tie the custom filter into the application from the Global.asax file

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
  filters.Add(new CustomFilter());
}
```

The problem is since the Authorize attribute runs before my custom filter I don't have the 
"Admin" role and i get a 401 - Unauthorized Access error.  How do I still keep the filter AND use the "Roles" tag in the Authorize attribute?

Answer (score 1):

In regards to

> "The problem is since the Authorize attribute runs before my custom
>   filter I don't have the "Admin" role"

You can create a another Authorize attribute which access the claims first, and then your standard Authorization which sets up the Admin.

The way you do this is to register and specify the Order property

```
filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute(), 1);
filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizeAttribute(), 2);
```

See more information on [Filter Ordering](http://blog.rajsoftware.com/post/2011/05/14/MVC3-Filter-Ordering.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

AuthorizeAttribute is no longer supported in MVC 4. You should now use the new AllowAnonymous attribute.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx

> ASP.NET MVC 4 includes the new AllowAnonymous attribute, you no longer need to write that code.  Setting the AuthorizeAttribute globally in global.asax and then whitelisting (That is, explicitly decorating the method with the AllowAnonymous attribute)  the methods you want to opt out of authorization is considered a best practice in securing your action methods.

If you attempt to use an action filter and override AuthorizeCore, you'll get a compile time error "There is no suitable method for override".

Here is another method of performing attribute authorization in MVC 4:

```
public class AuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
        response.Headers.Add("Location", "http://www.google.com");
        actionContext.Response = response;
    }
}
```